# What are class private names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python's [online documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) contains the description quoted below.
Could someone please explain what it means?

[2.3.2. Reserved classes of identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers)

> `__*` Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within
>   the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled
>   form to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base
>   and derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever code written inside a `class` uses a name that begins with two underscores but doesn't also end with two underscores the compiler replaces that name with a mangled form that includes the class name:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    __bar = None
    def set_bar(self, v):
        self.__bar = v


>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.set_bar(42)
>>> f.__dict__
{'_Foo__bar': 42}
```

What this means in practice is that when you create subclasses then (provided the subclass has a different name than the base class) you won't accidentally collide with the private names used in the base class.

It isn't a security mechanism as you can still get at the 'private' values using `getattr`, or even just the mangled form of the name, and it isn't perfect protection as sometimes class hierarchies have both base and derived classes with the same name.

Comment: you can actually get it using `f._Foo_bar` directly ☺

Comment: @zmo, yes you can. Why did that never occur to me? Added to my answer.